# Remove all padding from bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Hi how do i remove all padding and margins, footer and header spaces from bootstrap modal. All i want to see is the body fix exactly to my content.
Thanks in advance. Am using bootstrap 3? I am not using header and footer elements. only the modal,modal-dialog,modal-content and modal. So far i have the following but there is still space surrounding my content.

```
.modal-body {
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin: 0 ;
    padding: 0;
}
.modal-content{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
            <div class="modal  fade" id="tpModal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
                 aria-hidden="false">
                <div class="modal-dialog " role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">

                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <mycontent></mycontent>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to use `jquery` and set the `css` properties when the `modal` is `triggered`.

For this, you should handle `shown.bs.modal` event.

```js
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
   $(".modal-body").css("padding",'0px');
   $(".modal-body").css("margin",'0px');
   $(".modal-dialog").css({
              'position': 'relative',
              'display': 'table',
              'overflow-y': 'auto',    
              'overflow-x': 'auto',
              'width': 'auto',
              'min-width': '10px'
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" id="mymodal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        Lorem lorem lorem
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The fiddle above has a fixed width seems. reduce the text to a single word and see

Comment: @flexxxit, have a look to my answer.